# What happens with "var" variables inside a JavaScript Constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, var

example:

```
function Foo() {
    this.bla = 1;
    var blabla = 10;
    blablabla = 100;
    this.getBlabla = function () { 
        return blabla; // exposes blabla outside
    }
}

foo = new Foo();
```

**original question:**

I know that `bla` will be assigned to every instance of Foo.
What will happen with `blabla`?

**new question:**

what I understand now:

```
this.bla = 1;     // will become an attribute of every instance of FOO.
var blabla = 10;  // will become a local variable of Foo(**not** an attribute of every    instance of FOO), which could be accessed by any instance of FOO only if there's a method like "this.getBlabla".
blablabla = 100;  // will define a **new** (or change if exist) global(window) variable.
```

**[Question:]** Did i understand correctly?

Comment: Your edited example is correct -- EXCEPT that `blabla` is UNIQUE to EVERY INSTANCE of `Foo`.  So if `Foo` looked like `function Foo (number) { var blabla = number; this.bla = 37; this.getBlaBla = function () { return blabla; }; }` then `myFoo = new Foo(32);` and `yourFoo = new Foo(47);` would have completely different values for `.getBlaBla()`.  `myFoo.getBlaBla() === 32;  yourFoo.getBlaBla() === 47;`  It's important to remember that even though it's a `locally-scoped value` that it's unique to each instance, and isn't going to be the same value for any Foo to read/write in a shared way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any internal-methods you give to `this` -- ie: `this.method = function () {};` ***while inside*** of your Foo constructor function, are ***all*** going to have a reference to  the `blahblah` which is unique to each instance of a `Foo` object.

```
function Wallet () {
    var balance = 0;
    this.checkBalance = function () { return balance; };
    this.depositAmount = function (amount) { balance += amount; };
}


var wallet = new Wallet();
wallet.checkBalance();   // 0
wallet.depositAmount(3);
wallet.checkBalance();   // 3
```

But it's completely protected from access outside of wallet, unless you return it to somebody, from a privileged function.

```
wallet.balance; // undefined;
```

(added bit of interest -- if `balance` is a `string`, a `number`, or a `boolean`, even if you return it, that won't give people editing rights, or even permanent viewing access -- scalar variables are passed by value, so you're just passing the value of balance **at the time** -- if, however, balance was an `object`, a `function` or an `array`, they'd have permanent access to modify the crap out of your internal workings)

Note: methods ***HAVE*** to be assigned inside of the constructor for this to work.
Prototypes can't access internal variables.
Adding methods later won't give them access to internal variables.

This means that each instance will take up a little more memory, because each has its own copy of the methods, and has its own copy of the vars.
But if what you're doing requires private data, this would be a good way to get it.

Comment: thanks. so if i make anoter instance "var myOtherWallet = new Wallet();  then it will make another closure in the memory which includes another "var balance = 0" ?

Comment: @user1598423: Yes, each time you run the constructor it will create a new local variable, and when you associate methods with the object like that, each object will have its own instances of methods, with their own closures.

Comment: @Norguard &  @Daniel
even we can make array and objects   private along with  scaler variables by using spread operator eg.  `var balance =[1,2,3];
    this.checkBalance = function () { return [...balance]; };//{...obj}`

Answer (score 6):

In your example `blabla` is a local variable, so it will go away when the constructor function ends.

If you declare a function inside the constructor, which uses the variable, then the variable will be part of the closure for that function, and survives as long as the function (i.e. normally as long as the object):

```
function Foo() {
  this.bla = 1;
  var blabla = 10;

  this.getBlabla = function() {
    alert(blabla); // still here
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably mean that the variable survives as long as the *function*, or the *function object* so as to distinguish it from the constructed object.

Comment: so only variables that use "this" inside a contractor will become an attributes of the instances ? "var blabla = 10" will be only a local attribute of Foo - that will still exist only if there's a "this" method which uses it ?

Comment: @user1598423: When you use `this.name =` you add a property to the object, just as you can do `obj.name =` from outside the object. A local variable in the constructor is not associated to the object at all, only indirectly if it's used by a method in the object.

Answer (score 4):

It will become a **local** (think of 'private') variable within `Foo()`. Meaning that you can't access it outside of `Foo()`.

```
function Foo() {
  this.bla = 1; // this becomes an extension of Foo()
  var blabla = 10; // this becomes a "Local" (sort of like a 'private') variable
}
```

You could expose it (by returning it) with a Foo method.

```
function Foo() {
    var blabla = 10; // local

    this.getBlabla = function () { 
        return blabla; // exposes blabla outside
    }
}
```

Now outside of Foo():

```
var FooBar = new Foo();

var what_is_blabla = FooBar.getBlabla(); //what_is_blabla will be 10
```

[**jsFiddle demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/JYqpE/)

Comment: It's a **local** variable. I would avoid using the term "private" since it is used when talking about visibility in other languages (something JavaScript does not have).

Comment: You could add that other exposed functions can access `blabla`. So by adding `this.method = function(){ return blabla; };`, one could retrieve the content of `blabla`.

Comment: Good call Felix, forgot there technically aren't any "privates". Was actually just added that stuff Sirko too!

Comment: `Foo.getBlabla();` is incorrect as well.... should be `instanceOfFoo.getBlabla()`.

Comment: Just added the constructor it's working now. Somehow overlooked it!

Answer (score 3):

Variables declared with `var` inside a function used as a constructor will, like all other variables declared with `var` inside any function, be visible only during the execution of that function (unless the value is closed over using closures).

In other words, `blabla` is effectively invisible outside the function:

```
var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bla);     // 1
console.log(foo.blabla);  // throws NameError
```

By defining functions which close over these variables, they become the closest thing JavaScript has to "private" variables:

```
function Foo() {
    this.bla = 1;
    var private = 1;

    this.increment = function() {
        ++private;
    }

    this.getPrivateValue = function() {
        return private;
    }
}

foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bla);                // 1
foo.bla = 6;                         // legal
console.log(foo.bla);                // 6
console.log(foo.getPrivateValue());  // 1
// console.log(foo.private);         // would throw an error
foo.increment();                     // legal
console.log(foo.getPrivateValue());  // 2
// foo.getPrivateValue() = 5;        // syntax error. Still can't reassign to private no matter what you try!
```

Answer (score 1):

That variable is local to the constructor and won't be accessible outside of that scope (be it through `this` or otherwise), unless it is captured by a closure.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the var keyword, "blabla" becomes a global variable.  At other points in the code if you also use blabla without var, it will also be global, and you can accidentally change other instances of blabla and introduce unintended bugs in your code.  "var" puts the variable in the current scope, so in the case above, it's only accessible to Foo.

Answer (score -2):

`blabla` can almost be considered a private member of `Foo`.

See [this](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) article from Douglas Crockford.